# Is there a simple option for a PayPal button where amount is based on some user input?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, paypal

I'd like to have a PayPal button that charges a price based on two selections by the user, but I'm really not sure where to begin. I have a WordPress site but only a very basic understanding of JavaScript or jQuery.

Ideally there would be two sliders or input forms, and the price charged by the PayPal button changes based on what you choose/enter.

Example:

How many puppies do you currently have? (slider for 0 to 100)

How many puppies would you like to have in total? (slider for 0 to 100)

If the user has 99 puppies and only needs 1 more, they would be charged a minimal fee. But if they have 1 puppy and need 99 more, they would be charged a very large fee.

Really no idea where to begin, so any help at all is appreciated!

Comment: you can use normal paypal button html, then alter the values with js/jquery. as long as you have the right form elements on the form, you can change the values around and it will still submit just fine.

Comment: I'm reading up on the same subject and almost everything about the Paypal developer experience is horrific. They still use `MySQL_` on their example github sites as well as using magic quotes on their live IPN stuff, and their developer site is worded as if speaking to non-developers. Try [stripe](https://stripe.com/) instead. I wish our client would . . .

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://github.com/paypal/JavaScriptButtons). It should allow you to modulate the amount you want the button to have the user pay. I haven't personally tried it but it looks significantly easier to use than PayPal's [default button creation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/ht_create-pps-buttons/)